# Properties of Product of 4 consecutive even numbers +16

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[image]

**MyApproach**:
There is some integer $n \geq 1$ such that
$N=16+(n-1)(n)(n+1)(n+2)$,
so
$$
N = n^4 + 2n^3 - n^{2} -2n +16.
$$

But how to think to solve this problem? I am not getting to the result.

Comment: Four consecutive _even_ numbers, not consecutive numbers.

Comment: Oops .I think then N is a perfect square.I took $2$k,$4$k,$6$k,$8$k.

Comment: $n= 16 + (2k)(2k+2)(2k+4)(2k+6)$

Comment: Yes, it is a perfect square.

Comment: But the Ans given is $64$

Comment: By the way, the "multiplying out" move that you made in calculating $N$ is often a poor idea. Several reasons: (i) it is work: (ii) it is all too easy to make  a mistake: (iii) and, *most importantly* it destroys structure. Your expression as $16$ plus a product, though not quite right, had *structure*. Multiplying out produces an uninformative mess.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake in reading the question.Sorry for that but I am not aware how the Ans leads to $64$.

Comment: LIf we take the first set of 4 consecutive numbers then 16 is obtained as a product of two ie 2 and 8 so b is correct and also we can prove that it is also a perfect square so two options are correct ie b and d.

Comment: The answer is one of 0,1,2,3,4, since the question asks how many of the statements are always true. It turns out that (2) and (4) are always true, and the others are sometimes, indeed always, false, so the answer is 2.

Comment: @AndréNicolas HOW N is divisible by $64$ by seeing this equation 16[1+k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline**

Since for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$,

$ N = 16+2k(2k+2)(2k+4)(2k+6)=16[1+k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)] = [4(k^2 + 3k + 1)]^2$,

hence, N is a perfect square, and is clearly divisible by $16$.

When $k$ is odd, $k^2 + 3k + 1$ is odd, hence $16$ is the highest factor containing $2$ by which $N$ is divisible (thus eliminating $32$ and $64$)

You may verify this for $k = 1$ -  The first four of these $2, 4, 6, 8$ product with $16$ added gives $400$ which is neither divisible by $32$ nor $64$

**Summary**

Option $\color{blue}{C}$ being the right one.

Comment: But the Ans given is $64$

Comment: There are four options. How many of them are true is the question. My claim is that only (2) and (4) is true, ie. $\color{blue}{2}$ options.

Comment: I understood how 16 is divisible.But how the next number?

Comment: You mean you understood why it is divisible by 16.  It is not divisible by 32, because as I have shown, when k is odd, the other factor is odd. So we can't have 32 or 64.

Comment: Yes.I understood it is divisible by $16$.Whether we put k=1(or any OddNO) or k=2 (or any EvenNo).Adding to 16 The No will not be divisible by $32$ and .$64$.By putting k=0,we get $16$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
16+2k(2k+2)(2k+4)(2k+6)=16[1+k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)]
$$

Comment: How did you solve   after  that?I know it was a hint but 2 options cannot be true.

Comment: Prove that $1+k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)$ is a square.